# Retrieve top row only from the records that matches the conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a field that stores the seconds consumed by the process as a varchar. I'm doing a simple query to find the row that took the longest time using the following query in SQL server.

```
 select top 1 Cusip from Cusipprocesstime
        where 
        status != 'In Progress' and status is not null
        order by cast(status as decimal(18,7)) desc
```

Here status is set to  the number of seconds the process consumed. While in progress, status is set to 'In Progress'.

When I run the above query, if there are no records with the 'In Progress' status, then the query works fine.

If there are records with the status as 'In progress', the query fails stating 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Wondering, is there a way we can retrieve the top value only for records that matches the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check for numeric values before the conversion:

```
    select top 1 Cusip
    from Cusipprocesstime
    where status != 'In Progress' and status is not null
    order by (case when isnumeric(status) = 1 then cast(status as decimal(18,7)) end) desc;
```

SQL Server rearranges the order of operations.  In other words, it decides to do the conversion when the data is being read from the table -- which is before the `where` clause takes effect.  The `case` statement is the only statement that guarantees the order of evaluation (even subqueries and CTEs won't necessarily work here).  That is why this version works.

EDIT:

The ANSI standard specifies the *logical* order of the processing, and I believe SQL Server is consistent with that (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)).  The documentation is quite explicit, though:

> Note that the actual physical execution of the statement is determined
>   by the query processor and the order may vary from this list.

In particular (although not well documented), SQL Server adds new variables when a table is read into the system.  This makes sense, because the data is already being transformed from the physical format to the format used in memory, so adding new variables incurs little overhead.  In this case, the query is "thinking" something like:  "Gosh, I need to convert that value to a `decimal` for later on in the `order by` clause.  Let me do it right now, and just pass the value through the processing.  That'll be cheaper than trying to add it later on."

Comment: Love the last statement. 'Gosh. I need to...'